# How to efficiently cycle consecutive numbers c++

Tags: c++, performance

I am looking for a solution for cycling through consecutive numbers based on an input value. Similar to modulo, but different for negative numbers. Is there a better solution compared to the inefficient code below? Here is some input/output examples:

```
Numbers range 0 to 2
-2 -> 1
-1 -> 2
 0 -> 0
 1 -> 1
 2 -> 2
 3 -> 0
 4 -> 1

//Inefficient Code example
int getConsecutiveVal(int min, int max, int input) //Inclusive in this scenario
{
    while (input>max)
        input -= (1+max-min);
    while (input<min)
        input += (1+max-min);
    return input;
}

//Incorrect Code example since func(0,2,-1) returns 2
int getConsecutiveVal(int min, int max, int input)
{
    return (input % (1+max-min))+min;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, you need the modulo operator. The problem is that in C it doesn't work as expected for negative numbers.

If you know the minimum input value, you can just add a positive number `x` big enough to transform all negative numbers to positive. It won't affect the result if `x % R = 0` (in your example `R=3`.)

In your example, if you add, say, 3*10 to all inputs and perform the modulo operation you'll get the desired result:

```
mod(3*10+[-2 -1 0 1 2 3 4], 3) 

=     1     2     0     1     2     0     1
```

(the above is matlab notation and is specialized to the example you have presented. I'll leave it to you to extend it to arbitrary min/max)

#### A specific formula for the case you have presented:

You have suggested using

```
((input+abs(input)*(1+max-min)) % (1+max-min))+min
```

However, this formula **does not** work. For two reasons:

- First, if `input=0`, the `abs()` returns 0 and you get the minimum value as output (This is not always what your explicit while-based loop produces)
- Second, you forgot to subtract min from the input before the operation.

So the **correct formula** is the following (using `x` for input):

```
(x - xmin  + (1+abs(x))*(1+xmax-xmin)) % (1+xmax-xmin) + xmin
```

Comment: So, something like `((input+Math.abs(input)*(1+max-min)) % (1+max-min))+min` would use that logic, since the absolute value of the input * diff would always be positive when added to the input.

Comment: @RandomPerson323: close but not quite. See my updated answer. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 3):

To be able to increment *or* decrement, I used the following function. It's more than 1 line, but fewer math operations. It's similar in spirit to the original poster's format. Tested for positive and negative cases.

```
int16_t cycleIncDec(int16_t x, int16_t dir, int16_t xmin, int16_t xmax) {
    // inc/dec with constrained range
    // the supplied xmax must be greater than xmin
    x += dir;
    if      (x > xmax) x = xmin;
    else if (x < xmin) x = xmax;
    return x;
}
```

Output of cycleIncDec() with various start values and step sizes

```
x:  11: +1      0    1    2    3    4    5    6    0    1    2    3
x:   4: -1      3    2    1    0   -1   -2   -3   -4   -5   -6   -7
x:  -8: -1    -13  -12  -11  -10   -9   -8  -13  -12  -11  -10   -9
x:-190: -2   -192 -194 -196 -198 -200 -170 -172 -174 -176 -178 -180
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `%` twice to get you the right behaviour, since `a%b`, for positive `b`, is guaranteed to lie in `[-b+1, b+1]`.

```
int getConsecutiveVal(int min, int max, int input)
{
  int range_len = (1 + max - min);
  input -= min;
  return (((input % range_len) + range_len) % range_len) + min;
}
```

Comment: I would recommend just shifting values to make them all >= 0. An add/subtract is far more efficient than a second modulo.

Comment: Please see the "inefficient code" example.  The question asks to return min when the input is min, while your answer returns min when the input is zero. Adding `input -= min` in front of the return statement should fix the problem.